# chech/unchek all checkboxes (dynamically generated)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a view with checkboxes, generated dynamically, and a button for chech/unchek all the checkboxes. I try the code bellow but, the checkboxes are not checked ob button click event. Please help.
Thank you.

View with checkboxes:

```
 <button id="selectinvert" name="selectinvert" class="clear-selection ui-btn-hidden" aria-disabled="false" > Select / Deselect All</button>
    @for (int i = 0; i < @Model.workDaysList.Count; i++)
        {
              <div class="framed">
                 <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true" class="ui-btn-inner ui-corner-top ui-corner-bottom">
                   <h3>
                            <div class="ui-checkbox" id="checkbox">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="@Model.workDaysList[i][0]" />
                                <span class="ui-btn-text">
                                    <label for="@Model.workDaysList[i][0]" data-theme="c">
                                        @Model.workDaysList[i][1].Substring(6, 2)/@Model.workDaysList[i][1].Substring(4, 2)/@Model.workDaysList[i][1].Substring(0, 4)
                                    </label>
                                </span>
                                </div>
                            </h3>
                            @Model.detailDaysList[i][0] / @Model.detailDaysList[i][1]
                            <br />
                            @Model.detailDaysList[i][2] / @Model.detailDaysList[i][3]
                            <br />
                            @Model.detailDaysList[i][4] h
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
           }
```

Jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
       $("#selectinvert").click(function () {
       $("INPUT[type='checkbox']").each(function () {
                    if (this.checked == false) {
                        this.checked = true;
                    } else {
                        this.checked = false;
                    }
                });
          });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: What's not working? Come on! **-1** P.S. Put the code inside of DOM ready event

Comment: the checkboxes are not selected at button click

Comment: Any error in the console? Try help yourself first.

Comment: I made the adjustement indicated, but no change. The checkboxes are not selected, and I have no error in the console.

Comment: I don' t understand why my question have now -5? What is wrong?

Comment: You didn't give enough info,  and it doesn't look like you tried to solve the problem on your own. Maybe this is it?

Comment: I tried all the 7 solution offered by ths site users and I want to thank s them for support. I tried other soluion on the Internet. It doesn't work.May it the cause of <div data-role="collapsible">? When I make click on my collapsible, the coresponding checkbox is cheched and the collapsible content appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others suggest, you were missing closing brackets.

You could also shorten your code a bit:

```
$("#selectinvert").click(function() {
    $("input[type='checkbox']").each(function() {
        this.checked = !this.checked;
    });
});
```

Also note that your problem has nothing to do with ASP.NET or jQuery UI.
​

Comment: Thank you for suggestion on ASP.NET and jQuery UI. ​I try the code indicated, it doesn't select the checkboxes, and I have no error in console.

Comment: have you included jquery in your page? that would mean error in console anyway.. the code itself is not a problem, see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gNADc)

Answer (score 3):

**Try This:**

```
<script lang='javascript'>
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#selectinvert').click(function(){
         $("input[type='checkbox']").each(function (){
             if($(this).is(':checked')){
                 $(this).prop('checked', false);
             }else{
                 $(this).prop('checked', true);
             }
        });
     })
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

there are closing }) missing..

btw: the toggle can written like this:

```
this.checked = !this.checked
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to start with a basic HTML code and build upon that! Your model code might be braking your HTML. You can find the working prototype [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xf4tH/)!

```
<button id="selectinvert" name="selectinvert" class="clear-selection ui-btn-hidden" aria-disabled="false" > Select / Deselect All</button>
<div class="framed">
    <div class="ui-checkbox" id="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" id="@Model.workDaysList[i][0]" />
        <span class="ui-btn-text">First</span>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-checkbox" id="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" id="@Model.workDaysList[i][0]" />
        <span class="ui-btn-text">Second</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
$("#selectinvert").click(function() {

    $("INPUT[type='checkbox']").each(function() {
        if (this.checked == false) {
            this.checked = true;
        } else {
            this.checked = false;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
 $("#selectinvert").click(function () {
 $("INPUT[type='checkbox']").each(function () {
                if (!$(this).is(":checked")) {
                    $(this).attr('checked','checked');
                } else {
                    $(this).removeAttr('checked','checked');
                }
                })
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the code you have written will only only work when all the checkboxes are either checked or unchecked..
`What happens when some of them are checked..` Your code will just toggle those..

Your logic should be dependent on the button and not the checkboxes..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var isChecked = false;
    $("#selectinvert").click(function() {
        var $checkboxes = $("INPUT[type='checkbox']") ;
        if(isChecked){
            isChecked = false;
        }
        else{
            isChecked = true;
        }
        $checkboxes.prop('checked' , isChecked);
    });
});​
```